# Can Azure Logic apps only communicate one way?

Tags: azure-logic-apps

While designing work flow we add some trigger e.g. whenever new tweet is posted. We then need to add Frequency to poll that whether any activity is happened in twitter. My query is that

1. why we need to add this frequency?
2. Is there any way to automatically trigger the workflow whenever someone tweets with the hashtag we interested in or when there is new record added in salesforce?

Is there any way that Salesforce will send call back that new record is added?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start your workflow, it needs a trigger. For the twitter example and for the Saleforce, it will need a frequency that allows you to set how often (e.g every x minutes) do you want your workflow to check for new records (Salesforce) / tweets (Twitter).

Why do you need a frequency? Because the event exists in another system (Salesforce, Twitter, etc). To avoid that, you'll need to trigger the workflow from Twitter / Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks! this sounds me that we need some callback or webhook from Salesforce/twitter end to let our workflow know that some activity is happened.

Comment: exactly! The event belongs / comes from Twitter / Salesforce, I mean, you'll need a trigger over there, to call your azure logic app.

Answer (score 2):

Azure Logic Apps uses a serverless approach, it means that it needs some trigger to start the workflow and that it won't run forever. This is why you need to pass the frequency for this case.

If you want to monitor tweets 100% of the time, you'll need to use the stream API:
https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview

Comment: Thanks! My question is more generic than twitter specific. I mean in general for any connectors. Is there anyway that make Azure logic apps more event based. Lets say when Salesforce has record it will callback and let my workflow know that new record is added.

Comment: Yes, you just need to use the Salesforce connector. It will trigger your workflow. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-salesforce

Comment: Updated my question with screenshot, Salesforce connector is asking Frequency. I think you didn't get my question.